# What is the current state of the art method for a RESTful webservice?

Tags: web-services, rest, web, frameworks, asp.net-web-api

After I written most of my websites in a way which you don't even want to see, I now came to a point where I mostly think about what I am doing instead of just typing it. Some friends of mine and me now have developed a game. It is quite a mixture of good and bad styles, but thats another story. Now I want to reimplement our webservices to make it possible to host all our stuff with a single RESTful API.

My most important goal is to keep everything very clear and understandable. So I'd like to have a main system which, for example manages all users so you can address all users at http://example.com/user/XXXX

The next point is that I want to be able to have some resources for special sub-services like stats for a game which then is accesible at http://example.com/user/XXXX/gamename/stats  In this case the user management system should be able to authorize or reject the access and then redirect to the service which manages the game (e.g. another server).

Also the whole system should be able to make a difference between the game which calls the stats, or the user who wants to see his stats in the browser via our website)

Is there a state of the art way to implement a system like this?

Answer (score 0):

Your description of the problem is too vague, but from what I can understand I would suggest having a look at [Web Api](http://www.asp.net/web-api). For real-time communication between clients and server, also have a look at [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr).